# What are the usage and resource limits for odata queries on Azure Devops Server 2020 on-premises?

Tags: azure-devops, odata, analytics, azure-devops-server-2020, azure-devops-analytics

Does Azure Devops Server 2020 (on-prem) have any limits to the number of odata queries and/or amount of data returned in odata queries (for Analytics feature)?  I found this documentation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rate-limits?view=azure-devops-2020, but it implicitly refers to Azure Devops *Services* by referencing information such as Usage views/settings that are not available on-prem; so, I don't believe it to be accurate for AZD on-prem.

Comment: I donot think there is any limits to the number of odata queries and/or amount of data returned in odata queries. Check out below

Answer (score 0):

The documentation doesnot mention there is any limits to the number of odata queries. As for the amount of data returned in odata queries. The document has below:

> Analytics forces paging when query results exceed 10000 records. In that case, you will get first page of data and link to follow to get next page. Link (@odata.nextLink) can be found at the end of the JSON output. It will look like an original query followed by $skip or $skiptoken

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/odata-query-guidelines?view=azure-devops#-do-use-server-driven-paging) for more information.

So i donot think there is any limits to the number of odata queries and/or amount of data returned in odata queries.

It is described in the document that the [rate limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rate-limits?view=azure-devops-2020#current-rate-limits) delay requests from individual users when their usage exceeds threshold  consumption of a resource within a (sliding) five-minute window. So the rate limits donot have effect on the number of odata queries and/or amount of data returned in odata queries but the frequency the odata queries call Azure Devops Services.